# Is there a different approach to evaluate $\int \ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x?$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

The usual method of evaluating $\int \ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ requires you to rewrite it as 
$$
\int \ln(x) \cdot \color{brown}1\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and apply integration by parts.

Letting $u=\ln(x)$ and $\mathrm{d}v=\color{brown}1 \,\mathrm{d}x$, we get that $\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x$ and $v=\int \color{brown}1 \,\mathrm{d}x = x$, so our integral becomes

\begin{align}
\int \ln(x) \cdot \color{brown}1\,\mathrm{d}x
&=uv-\int v\,\mathrm{d}u
\\[0.5em]
&=x\ln(x)-\int x\cdot\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\\[0.5em]
&=x\ln(x)-\int \mathrm{d}x
\\[0.5em]
&=x\ln(x)-x+c
\end{align}

After looking through many calculus books, this is the only method I've found to integrate $\ln(x)$. Are there any other methods one could use to integrate the function $\ln(x)?$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always eliminate the log by substituting $x=e^u$.  We have
$$\int\ln x\,dx=\int ue^u\,du\ .$$
Now you will still need integration by parts, but in this case it's a pretty obvious integration by parts which does not rely on the "trick" of inserting a factor of $1$.

Comment: Of course, all or most answers in this post will be fine. But I feel there's a pedagogic intention in the question, so I really like this answer. While the 'trick' of taking the whole integral as $u$ might look as 'tricky' as adding the one factor when doing by parts, I feel it more natural and, most important, substitution is usually learnt and practiced before parts, so at this instance this one can be seen as an exercise applying both cases (then, the alternative, less natural proof can be given for comparison).

Comment: It’s a bit curious use integration by parts as an alternative to interpretation by parts, btw “de gustibus...” ;)

Comment: @gimusi Did you read the last 24 words of my answer?

Comment: Yes of course! But since we know that (ln x)’=1/x choose x as second function to integrate by parts seems pretty obvious to me. Btw nothing against your answer, I also upvoted! Bye

Comment: Sorry, this was the first thing I too thought, but I don't think its a different method, we go back to by parts only.

Answer (score 6):

By trial solution

$$F(x)=a(x)\log x+b(x) \implies F’(x)=a’(x) \log x+\frac{a(x)}{x}+b’(x)$$

then

- $a’(x)=1\implies a(x)=x$
- $b’(x)=-1\implies b(x)=-x$

Answer (score 4):

Rough reasoning:
\begin{align*}
\ln x&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{n}(x-1)^{n}\\
\int\ln xdx&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n+1}(x-1)^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)(x-1)^{n+1}\\
&=(x-1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{n}(x-1)^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+2}\dfrac{1}{n+1}(x-1)^{n+1}\\
&=(x-1)\ln x+\ln x-(x-1)\\
&=x\ln x-x+c.
\end{align*}

Comment: Is this not only for restricted domain of $x$? (0,2) ?

Comment: So I have emphasized that it is a rough reasoning.

Comment: I did thought of this method but as mentioned by @King tut the restricted domain

Answer (score 3):

Since for $t>1$ (the other case is similar) $\int_1^t \ln x dx$ is the (positive) area of the region $D\subset \mathbb R^2$ enclosed by the curve $y=\ln x$, the straight line $x=t$ and the horizontal axis, this area can also be written as a double integral $\iint_D dA$, which by Fubini theorem equals the iterated integral
$$\int_1^t \int_0^{\ln x} dy\, dx.$$

Changing order of integration by writing $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \colon 0\le y\le \ln t \wedge e^y \le x \le t\}$, that integral is equal to
$$\int_0^{\ln t} \int_{e^y}^t dx\,dy=\int_0^{\ln t} (t-e^y) \;dy=(ty-e^y)|_{y=0}^{\ln t}=t \ln t -t+1.$$

That is,
$$\int \ln x \; dx= x \ln x -x+C.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for, but we can "discover" $\int\ln x\;\text dx$ by differentiating the function $x\ln x$.

By using the product rule we get:

$$\frac{\text d}{\text dx}\left(x\ln x\right)=1 + \ln x$$

This means that:

$$\begin{align}\int\left(1+\ln x\right)\text dx&=x\ln x+C\\x+\int\ln x\;\text dx&=x\ln x + C\\\int\ln x\;\text dx&=x\left(\ln x - 1\right)+C\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

For fun, a bit of trickery:

Let $x=e^y$.

Then:

$\displaystyle \int ln x dx = \displaystyle \int ye^y dy$;

Now look at :

$ \dfrac{d}{dy} (ye^y) = e^y +ye^y$.

Thus:

$\displaystyle \int ye^y dy =$

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{d}{dy}(ye^y) - \displaystyle \int e^y dy =$

$ye^y -e^y =  x \ln x - x +C$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x = e^y$ and $y= \ln x$.

$\int \ln x \, dx = \int y \, dx = \int y \frac{dx}{dy}dy = \int y e^y dy = y e^y - e^y + C=  x \ln x -x  + C$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \ln x dx\tag1 $$

Let $y=\ln x$ then ${dy\over dx}={1\over x}$, $dx=xdy$

and $x=e^y$

$$\int yxdy=\int ye^ydy\tag2$$

now using the series of $e^y$: $$e^y=1+y+{y^2\over 2!}+{y^3\over 3!}+\cdots\tag3$$

$$\int ye^ydy=\int \left(y+y^2+{y^2\over 2!}+{y^3\over  3!}+\cdots\right)dy\tag4$$

$$\int ye^ydy={y^2\over 2}+{y^3\over 3\cdot 1}+{y^4\over 4\cdot 2!}+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{y^{n+2}\over (n+2)n!}=y\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{y^{n+1}\over (n+1)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{y^{n+2}\over (n+2)!}\tag5$$

$$\int ye^ydy=y\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{y^{n+1}\over (n+1)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{y^{n+2}\over (n+2)!}=y(e^y-1)-(e^y-1-y)\tag6$$

Simplify
$$\int ye^y dy=y(e^y-1)-(e^y-1-y)=ye^y-e^y+1\tag7$$

$e^y=x$ and $y= \ln x$

$$\int ye^y dy=x\ln x-x+1\tag8$$

$$\int \ln x dx=x\ln x-x+C\tag9$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\color{red}{\int \ln (x) \, dx}=\\\underset{n\to 0}{\text{lim}}\int \left(-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{x^n}{n}\right) \, dx=\\\underset{n\to
   0}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x^{1+n}}{n (1+n)}\right)+C=\\\underset{n\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{-x-n x+x^{1+n}}{n
   (1+n)}+C=\\\frac{\underset{n\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{-x+x^{1+n}-x n}{n}}{\underset{n\to 0}{\text{lim}}(1+n)}+C=\\\underset{n\to
   0}{\text{lim}}\frac{-x+x^{1+n}-x n}{n}+C=\\\underset{n\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(-x+x^{1+n} \ln (x)\right)+C=\color{red}{\\\ x \ln (x)-x+C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $\log x$; that is to say, $F'(x) = \log x$.  Then by the Fundamental Theorem, $$\int_{x=1}^c \log x \, dx = F(c) - F(1).$$  But the LHS is simply the area under the curve of $\log x$ from $x = 1$ to $x = c$.  If $c > 1$, this is also the area below the line $y = c$ but above the curve $y = e^x$ from $x = 0$ to $x = \log c$; that is to say, $$\int_{x=1}^c \log x \, dx = \int_{x=0}^{\log c} c - e^x \, dx = \Bigl[ cx - e^x \Bigr]_{x=0}^{\log c} = (c \log c - e^{\log c}) - (0 - 1) = c \log c - c + 1.$$  Consequently we may take $F(c) = c \log c - c$.

If $0 < c < 1$, then the area corresponds instead to $$-\int_{x=\log c}^0 e^x - c \, dx,$$ which of course yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of calculus implies that
$$ f(x)=\int_1 ^x \ln u \mathrm{d} u $$
gives an anti-derivative, and all others differ from this one by an additive constant. We further have
$$f(x)=\int_1^x \int_1^u \frac{1}{v} \mathrm{d}v \mathrm{d} u, $$
and using the Fubini-Tonelli theorem gives
$$f(x)=\int_1^x \int_v^x \frac{1}{v} \mathrm du \mathrm{d} v=\int_1^x  \left(\frac{x}{v}-1 \right) \mathrm{d} v=x \ln x-(x-1). $$
It follows that the indefinite integral
$$\int \ln x \mathrm{d} x= x \ln x-x+C. $$