# Exercise: A first-order linear differential equation with $x^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a question I'll be giving to my students on a quiz, and I want to have a solution typed up nicely for them. Hopefully posting it as a question here will help future students too.

> For $x>0$, how do you solve the differential equation
>
> #### $$x^x\dot{y} + \ln\left(x^{x^x}\right)y = 1\,?$$

I'll probably write $\ln\left(x^{x^x}\right)$ as $x^x\ln(x)$ on the quiz though; I don't want them to get tripped up on that since that's not what I'm quizzing them on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This differential equation looks linear, but let's actually write it in the standard form of a first-order linear differential equation, $\dot{y} + p(x)y = q(x) \newcommand{\ex}{\mathrm{e}}$ before we continue, just to be sure.

\begin{align}
x^x\dot{y} + \ln\left(x^{x^x}\right)y &= 1
\\[0.5em]
x^x\dot{y} + x^x\ln\left(x\right)y &= 1
\\[0.5em]
\dot{y} + \ln\left(x\right)y &= x^{-x}
\end{align}

Since $x>0$, $x^x \neq 0$, so dividing through by $x^x$ doesn't cause any problems. So yeah, it's linear. Nifty! Now we [recall that we can solve a first-order linear differential equation by multiplying through by the integrating factor $\ex^{\int p(x) \mathrm{d}x}$](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) which allows us to "undo the derivative of a product" on the left-hand side. In terms of a general first-order linear differential equation, this looks like

\begin{align}
\dot{y} + p(x)y &= q(x)
\\[0.5em]
\ex^{\int p(x) \mathrm{d}x}\dot{y} + \ex^{\int p(x) \mathrm{d}x}p(x)y &= \ex^{\int p(x) \mathrm{d}x}q(x)
\\[0.5em]
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\ex^{\int p(x) \mathrm{d}x}{y}\right) &= \ex^{\int p(x) \mathrm{d}x}q(x)
\,.
\end{align}

For our particular differential equation though, after we [remember that $\int \ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = x\ln(x)-x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719890/167197), this integrating factor is
$$
\ex^{\int \ln(x) \mathrm{d}x}
=\ex^{x\ln(x)-x}
=\ex^{\ln(x^x)}\ex^{-x}
=x^x\ex^{-x}
\,,
\color{maroon}{\LARGE^\star}
$$
and our differential equation becomes

\begin{align}
\dot{y} + \ln\left(x\right)y &= x^{-x}
\\[0.5em]
\ex^{\int \ln(x) \mathrm{d}x}\dot{y} + \ex^{\int \ln(x) \mathrm{d}x}\ln\left(x\right)y &= \ex^{\int \ln(x) \mathrm{d}x}x^{-x}
\\[0.5em]
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\ex^{\int \ln(x) \,\mathrm{d}x}y\right) &= \ex^{\int \ln(x) \mathrm{d}x}x^{-x}
\\[0.5em]
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^x\ex^{-x} y\right) &= x^x\ex^{-x}x^{-x}
\\[0.5em]
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^x\ex^{-x} y\right) &= \ex^{-x}
\,.\end{align}

Then by taking the antiderivative of both sides we get

\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^x\ex^{-x} y\right) \,\mathrm{d}x &= \int \ex^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\\[0.5em]
x^x\ex^{-x} y &= C-\ex^{-x}
\\[0.5em]
y &= \frac{C-\ex^{-x}}{x^x\ex^{-x}}
\\[0.5em]
y &= \frac{C\ex^x-1}{x^x}
\end{align}

There's no problem dividing through by $\ex^{-x}$ since $\ex^{-x}$ is never zero, so this is our general solution.

---

$\color{maroon}{\LARGE \star}$ An astute reader might ask at this point, *shouldn't there be a constant of integration inside the exponent here? Shouldn't it be $\ex^{x\ln(x)-x+k}$?* That astute reader would be correct, but eventually the constant $k$ can be absorbed into the constant $C$ that appears later in the calculation. An explicit calcuation of this can be found in [Paul's Lecture Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx), but after you see this once and realize that this is what happens, you can safely drop the constant of integration $k$ that should appear at this step.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^xy'+\ln(x^{x^x}) y =1$$
$$x^xy'+x^x\ln x y =1$$

Observe that
$$(x^x)'=(e^ {x \ln x})'=x^x(x \ln x)'=x^x( \ln x +1)$$
Now
$$x^xy'+x^x\ln x y +x^xy=1+x^xy$$
$$(x^xy)'=1+x^xy$$
$$\implies z'=1+z$$
Where $z=x^xy$
It's easy to solve
$$(x^xye^{-x})'=e^{-x}$$
After integration
$$x^xye^{-x}=-e^{-x}+K$$
$$\boxed {y=\frac  {Ke^x-1}{x^x}}$$